# How can I calculate the perimeter of an equation-defined curve？

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is how the curve looks like:

```
img = ContourPlot[
                  1/x + 3/4 (((y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x)^2 + 1) Exp[
                  ArcTan[(y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x] - Pi/6] == 0,
           {x, -3, 1}, 
           {y, -(1/5), 4},
       PlotPoints -> 70 ]
```

[image]

[@xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) comes up with a (kinka hacky!) solution, which extract the coordinates forming that curve:

```
Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ 
  Partition[First@Cases[Normal@img, 
                        Line[a_] :> a, Infinity], 2, 1]
      ]

  (* 9.85614 *)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: "kinka hacky" is nice as it is more generic?

Comment: @chris maybe :D

Comment: @chris The fatal defect of this method is, it can't control the `Precision`. The result is always `MachinePrecision`, and the influence from `PlotPoints` is also big: `PlotPoints -> 70` gives `9.92371`, `-> 200` gives `9.85703`, `-> 300` gives `9.84398`, `-> 400` gives `9.84211`…

Comment: @xzczd sure; on the other hand its not always trivial to find a parametrization as you did below??

Comment: @chris So I'm still looking forward to a general numeric solution though b.gatessucks had solved it analytically :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a parametric representation for your curve :

```
eqn = 1/x +  3/4 (((y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x)^2 + 1) Exp[ArcTan[(y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x] - Pi/6] ;

aux = First@Solve[(eqn /. {y -> 1/Sqrt[3] + t x}) == 0, x]
(* {x -> -((4 E^(\[Pi]/6 - ArcTan[t]))/(3 (1 + t^2)))} *)

solx = aux[[1, 2]]
(* -((4 E^(\[Pi]/6 - ArcTan[t]))/(3 (1 + t^2))) *)

soly = 1/Sqrt[3] + t x /. aux
(* 1/Sqrt[3] - (4 E^(\[Pi]/6 - ArcTan[t]) t)/(3 (1 + t^2)) *)

Plot[{solx, soly}, {t, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: sol]

It looks like you get the curve with `t` in `[-500,500]` - you might need to improve on the interval.

```
ParametricPlot[{solx, soly}, {t, -500, 500}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: plot]

The last step is just the usual definition of arclength (thanks to @MichaelE2):

```
NIntegrate[ Sqrt[Simplify[(D[solx, t])^2 + (D[soly, t])^2 ]], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 9.83926 *)
```

Comment: Very nice, but I think the limits should be `{t, -Infinity, Infinity}`, at least on the integral.

Comment: Oh, parametric representation… I should have not given up the effort for getting analytic solution so easily…

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In version 10, you can also do this:

```
eqn = 1/x + 3/4 (((y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x)^2 + 1) Exp[ArcTan[(y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x] - Pi/6] == 0;
region = ImplicitRegion[eqn, {{x, -3, 1}, {y, -1/5, 4}}];
ArcLength@DiscretizeRegion[region, AccuracyGoal -> 6]
(* 9.83926 *)
```

But you have to set the `AccuracyGoal` yourself, and I'm not sure it gives any guarantees on the accuracy of the arc length itself. Sadly applying `ArcLength` directly to `region` fails with "*Unable to compute the length of region ImplicitRegion[...]*."

Answer (score 2):

In the case that one cannot solve the equation for a symbolic parametric representation, then `NDSolve` can be used to do so numerically.  And while we're at it, we may as well integrate the arclength.  In the code below, we compute an arc length parametrization, so the parametrization returns to it's starting point when the parameter `s` equals the total arc length of the loop.

```
ClearAll[f, x, y];
eqn = 1/x +  3/4 (((y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x)^2 + 1) Exp[ArcTan[(y - 1/Sqrt[3])/x] - Pi/6] == 0;
cplot = ContourPlot[Evaluate @ eqn, {x, -3, 1}, {y, -(1/5), 4}];
f[x_, y_] = eqn /. Equal -> Subtract // Together // Numerator // Simplify;
grad[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}];
unitTangent[x_, y_] = #/Sqrt[#.#] &@Cross@grad[x, y];
p0 = NestWhile[                       (* Newton's method to find starting point *)
   With[{g = grad @@ #},                 (* use gradient for derivative *)
     # - (f @@ #) g / g.g                (* Newton's method step *)
     ] &,
   cplot[[1, 1, 1]],                     (* start at a point on the contour plot *)
   Abs[#1 - #2]/Norm[#1] > 1*^-15 &,     (* stopping criterion *)
   2,
   20                                    (* no more than 20 iterations *)
   ];

sol = First@NDSolve[{
     {x'[s], y'[s]} == unitTangent[x[s], y[s]], {x[0], y[0]} == p0,
     WhenEvent[x[s] > p0[[1]], "StopIntegration"]},
    {x, y}, {s, 0, Infinity}];

x["Coordinates"] /. sol // Last // Last
% - NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[Simplify[(D[solx, t])^2 + (D[soly, t])^2]], {t, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}]
(*
  9.83926         - arc length
  8.24538*10^-7   - error (compared to b.gatessucks's result)
*)
```

Remarks: (1) One might need extra conditions for the stopping condition `WhenEvent[x[s] > p0[[1]]...` in the case of more complicated curve.  (2) The error when starting at `p0 = cplot[[1, 1, 1]]` is almost `0.001`, so it is probably worth improving it in most cases.